# How do I find how many of the candidates were correctly classified in the decision tree?

Tags: r, decision-tree, confusion-matrix

Made data:

```
TrainIndex <- sample(1:929,
                     size = round(0.7*929),
                     replace = FALSE)
train_data <- elecdatacomp[TrainIndex,]
test_data <- elecdatacomp[-TrainIndex,]
```

Built Tree:

```
tree1 <- rpart(gen_election ~ twitter + facebook + youtube, data = train_data)
```

What I have right now:

```
predicted_value <- predict(tree1, test_data)
pred <- factor(ifelse(predicted_value[,2] > 0.5, 1,0))
confMatTree1 <- confusionMatrix(pred, test_data$gen_election, positive = levels(test_data$gen_election)[2])
```

**Error**:

> Error in confusionMatrix.default(pred, test_data$gen_election,
> positive = levels(test_data$gen_election)[2]) :*    The data must
> contain some levels that overlap the reference.

Comment: Is test_data$gen_election a factor? Try unique(pred) and unique(test_data$gen_election) to see which levels each takes. The error you're seeing is because the two don't seem to both be factors with the same levels.

Comment: They both return two levels

Comment: They're also both factors

Comment: If you search for that error message you'll find lot of relevant results. Here are some related posts on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+The+data+must+contain+some+levels+that+overlap+the+reference. Have you tried solutions from them?